# Trying to sort an array of randomized integers from biggest to smallest using a bubble sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So as part of a task, I was asked to create an array with randomized values within a range, and then to sort it from smallest to biggest (I used a bubble sort), and then to firstly, print the sum of all the elements in the array, then to list them from smallest to biggest.

My issue is that I keep getting the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error, but cannot find where this problem lies.

You can see in the code that I've put in the randomArrays method, a for loop that creates the random values for the array size I declared in the main method, then, underneath the for loop, I've created an if statement that checks to see if an element's value is bigger than the element after it, if it is, it swaps the place of the elements, until they're all sorted into smallest to biggest, and the loop is terminated.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you :)

```
public class MyArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] elements = new int[50];
    int min = 0;
    int max = 50;

    randomArrays(elements, max, min);

}

public static void randomArrays(int[] elements, int max, int min) {
    int range = max - min; //defines the range of the integers
    int temp;
    boolean fixed = false;

    while (fixed == false) {
        fixed = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i] = min + (int) (Math.random() * range);
            while (i < elements.length) {
                if (elements[i] > elements[i + 1]) {
                    //if 8   >    5
                    temp = elements[i + 1];
                    //store 5 in temp
                    elements[i + 1] = elements[i];
                    //put the 8 in the 5's place
                    elements[i] = temp;
                    fixed = false;
                }
                i++;
            }

        }
    }

}
//System.out.println(elements[i]);
}
```

Comment: You access `elements[i + 1]` but `i` goes up to `elements.length - 1` inclusive. This will be out of bounds, as a debugger would tell you.

Answer (score 1):

> My issue is that I keep getting the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
>   error, but cannot find where this problem lies.

Problem lies in the condition of the `for loop`. You get `ArrayOutOfBounds` exception when `i=49` and then you try to access `i+1` index which doesn't exists.

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements.length-1; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can already see that your code is going out of the arrays limit.
if you look at your code, following is where this is happening

```
while (i < elements.length) {
```

Its this while loop part, so if you change it to correctly loop thru the right number of elements, your problem will be resolved..change your while loop code with this one

```
while (i < elements.length-1) {
```